# Is this formula valid / true preserving? $\wedge_{i=1}^{n}\left(A_i \leftrightarrow A_{2i}\right)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n \geq 2$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Is this formula valid / true preserving?
>
> $$\wedge_{i=1}^{n}\left(A_i \leftrightarrow A_{2i}\right) \text{ for
> }n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ with } n \geq 2$$

As I understood from wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity), a propositional formula is valid if every entry in the truth table is true. It is true preserving if at least one entry is true.

But I'm not quite sure how you would write this formula, that $\wedge_{i=1}^{n}$ should work similar to the sum symbol, right?

So as example, we have $\wedge_{i=1}^{2}: (A_1 \leftrightarrow A_{2}) \wedge (A_2 \leftrightarrow A_{4})$ is it correct like that?

If so, I would just take some of these and create a truth table and make a conclusion.

```
A1    A2    A1↔A2    A2↔A4    (A1↔A2)∧(A2↔A4)     
 0     0      1        1             1
 0     1      0        0             0
 1     0      0        0             0
 1     1      1        1             1
```

The table should continue like that for every other $n$ (I don't need to prove that). So because the last entries aren't all $1$ aka true, the formula is not valid but it is true preserving because we have some true entries, for example the model $$I(A_{1}) = I(A_{2}) = I(A_{4}) = 0 \text{ (I didn't write  } A_4 \text{ into the table to keep it a little more clear.)}$$

Is it correct like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that these formulas are not valid: for a general proof, you can easily show that when you set $A_1$ to False, and all others to True, the statement will evaluate to False.

You are also correct that these formulas are truth-preserving, but your reasoning wasn't correct, since you didn't quite have the right definition of truth-preservation.

A truth-preserving statement is one where, if you assign True to all the atomic propositions involved, the statement as a whole evaluates to True.

That is clearly the case here, so it is truth-preserving.

(so the difference with your reasoning is that it is not enough to point out that there will be *some* row where the statement evaluates to True, but that it evaluates to True in a *specific* row, namely the one where all atomic propositions are set to True)